# Linux, the only way to GAIN root access is executing a setuid-root file?

Tags: linux, unix, root, setuid

Is my assumption true, that on Unix/Linux, the only way to GAIN root access is to execute a setuid-root file?

In other words, the system calls `setuid()`, `setgid()` are all about DROPPING privileges?

Please note that my question is not about exploits.

Comment: Yes, and that is why [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) is about

Comment: Well, one can also "gain" root access by forking from a root process. The problem is that any process that you _could_ conceivably fork from either has already dropped root privilegues long before giving control to your process (think init) or was itself forked from a process that dropped privilegues earlier (think bash).

Comment: By GAIN I mean that a non-root process becomes a root process. Not that a root process creates another root process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's true. The only way for a non-root process (assuming it's running a non-setuid program) to become root is to exec a setuid program. If it's running a set-uid root program, then its effective uid is root and real uid is whoever ran it. It can then do setuid(0) to make its real uid 0.